# git push origin master fatal error

Tags: git

I ran into an error when trying to push my work from terminal on my mac OS, and was hoping someone may be able to help! I've tried both the ssh protocol and https: protocol when cloning from my GitHub account, but the same fatal message shows up.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Jacobs-MacBook-Pro:bloc-jams JYUN$ ls
index.html
Jacobs-MacBook-Pro:bloc-jams JYUN$ git clone       
https://github.com/sekkinsan/bloc-jams.git
Cloning into 'bloc-jams'...
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Jacobs-MacBook-Pro:bloc-jams JYUN$ 
Jacobs-MacBook-Pro:bloc-jams JYUN$ git add .
Jacobs-MacBook-Pro:bloc-jams JYUN$ git commit -m "commit html and css"
[master (root-commit) 929806f] commit html and css
 2 files changed, 27 insertions(+)
 create mode 160000 Desktop/bloc/bloc-jams/bloc-jams
create mode 100644 Desktop/bloc/bloc-jams/index.html
**Jacobs-MacBook-Pro:bloc-jams JYUN$ git push origin master
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.**
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you get when you run: git remote -v

Comment: afaik, when you run 'git clone', if you don't provide a directory (like ./), it will create a new directory. In this case a directory called block-jams (inside your current block-jams directory). Can you make sure?

Comment: Are you giving the Push command in the root directory of `bloc-jams` directory/folder?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all of your help! I wasn't quite able to figure out what was the issue but after waiting a day and trying it again it worked...

Posted terminal tasks below for reference. 
Thank you again for the help.

```
Jacobs-MacBook-Pro:bloc-jams JYUN$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

new file:   index.html

Jacobs-MacBook-Pro:bloc-jams JYUN$ git commit -m "first commit"
[master 499626c] first commit
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 index.html
Jacobs-MacBook-Pro:bloc-jams JYUN$ git remote add origin     https://github.com/sekkinsan/bloc-jams.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
Jacobs-MacBook-Pro:bloc-jams JYUN$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 279 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/sekkinsan/bloc-jams.git
   0cf6475..499626c  master -> master
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case your current directory is a workspace of a local repo with no remote.

bloc/bloc-jams/

When you run `git clone` it will generate a new workspace in a subdirectory.

bloc/bloc-jams/bloc-jams/

Unless you change into that directory you don't see the remote for that directory.